# add conditional filter to sales_order_grid collection (magento2)

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, uicomponent, order-grid

I want to add a custom filter to the order collection, checking if some conditions are met. A helper method should return false/true, and then apply the custom filter if it returns true. The custom filter is just a boolean returned from a custom column added to sales_order table. Basically, I want to show the orders that have this column value set as true only to a specific admin user and hide them from the other admin users. Of course, this should only be applied to the admin sales order grid.

I am just starting to learn about the UI components and I have no idea how could I achieve this using the new system.

Should I go with a class preference for the grid collection instead? Should I add a plugin to a relevant method maybe?

I'm hoping that some more advanced users can help me choosing the best path for this.

Thanks!